# NodeJs and ElasticSearch: Bulk insert error: Failed to derive xcontent

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, bulkinsert

I can't find my mistake, I am trying to insert an array of the element into Elastic Search using the bulk method with elasticsearch library.

Thanks in advance.

```
InserTweets: function (arrayobj, callback) {

        var items=[];

        var count=1;
        arrayobj.forEach(element => {
            items.push({ index:  { _index: 'twitter', _type: 'tweet', _id: count }},element);
            count++;
        });

        console.log(items);

        client.bulk({body: [items]}, function (err, resp, status) {
            callback(err, resp, status);
        });
    }
```

Error:

```
{ error:
   { root_cause: [ [Object] ],
     type: 'parse_exception',
     reason: 'Failed to derive xcontent' },
  status: 400 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of the property `body` has to be an array of objects, not an array of array of objects.

This `client.bulk({body: [items]}...` should be `client.bulk({body: items}...`

Furthermore, you're pushing into `items` the `element` itself as well, is this what you want?